# Why aren't my icons showing?

Tags: html, css

This is my css code for my icons, the css code also changed my background and other stuff in my webpage how come. A lot of this CSS code is effecting my HTML code sort of making it not established i added colors but they won't run over the CSS code.

```
html {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #dde7f2;
        padding: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

/* Wrapper */
.icon-button {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3.6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2.0rem;
    height: 3.6rem;
    line-height: 3.6rem;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    width: 3.6rem;
}

/* Circle */
.icon-button span {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 0;
}
.icon-button:hover span {
    width: 3.6rem;
    height: 3.6rem;
    border-radius: 3.6rem;
    margin: -1.8rem;
}
.twitter span {
    background-color: #4099ff;
}
.facebook span {
    background-color: #3B5998;
}
.google-plus span {
    background-color: #db5a3c;
}

/* Icons */
.icon-button i {
    background: none;
    color: White;
    height: 3.6rem;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 3.6rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
    width: 3.6rem;
    z-index: 10;
}
.icon-button .icon-twitter {
    color: #4099ff;
}
.icon-button .icon-facebook {
    color: #3B5998;
}
.icon-button .icon-google-plus {
    color: #db5a3c;
}
.icon-button:hover .icon-twitter,
.icon-button:hover .icon-facebook,
.icon-button:hover .icon-google-plus {
    color: White;
}
```

This is my html code, creating links, is there something i should add or delete. The

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Andis Place</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="stylesheet.css"/>

    </head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <body style="font-family:Courier New;" bgcolor="White"
    <head>
            <h1 style="color:Orange;"> <center>Welcome to Andis Place</center></h1>
        </head>
    </body>

    <body>
    <p style="font-size:15px;">Enjoy… </p>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
 <style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dde7f2;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #dde7f2;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color:#dde7f2;
    color:Blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul>

  <li class="external-link">
          <a href="https://soundcloud.com/palomazee" target="_blank">Soundcloud</a>
        </li>
 <li class="external-link">
          <a href="" target="_blank">Shop</a>
        </li>
  <li class="external-link">
          <a href="" target="_blank">Photos</a>
        </li>
  <li class="external-link">
          <a href="" target="_blank">About Me</a>
        </li>
</ul>

</body>


<head>

<style>


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: White;
}

li {
    float: center;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: Blue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color:Powderblue;
}

.active {
    background-color: #dde7f2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
**<a href="http://twitter.com/minimalmonkey" class="icon-button twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i><span></span></a>
<a href="http://facebook.com" class="icon-button facebook"><i class="icon-facebook"></i><span></span></a>
<a href="http://plus.google.com" class="icon-button google-plus"><i class="icon-google-plus"></i><span></span></a>**

</body>












</html>
```

[image: That is the fancy links with no icons inside.]

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in your code that shows where the icons are actually coming from.. are they images? Fonts?

Comment: The icons sections i believed contained the contents, my first time trying to add social media icons, how would i add the actual icons inside the circle contents.

Comment: You'll need to decide where to get these images from - you can use images (PNG, JPEG), SVG or an Icon Font. Check out [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/), a common, relatively simple way to include social media icons in your site.